# When I press Docker button in Visual Studio Pro, what Docker command is running actually?

Tags: docker, visual-studio

[image]

Let's say if I "Enable Docker" when I create a project using Visual Studio and then press the "Docker" icon, what docker command actually is running?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Quickstart: Docker in Visual Studio / Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools?view=vs-2022#debug)", it looks like a `docker build` (which will start with downloading base images) + `docker run`.

> ### Debug
>
> Select `Docker` from the debug drop-down in the toolbar, and start debugging the app.
> You might see a message with a prompt about trusting a certificate; choose to trust the certificate to continue.
>
> The Container Tools option in the Output window shows what actions are taking place.
>
> [image: debug]
>
> The first time, it might take a while to download the base image, but it's much faster on subsequent runs.
>
> After building, the browser comes up and your app's home page is shown.
> In the browser's address bar, you can see the localhost URL and port number for debugging.